# Laravel application on Azure Web App with PHP8 / NGINX keeps redirecting to .azurewebsites.net url, instead of custom domain

Tags: laravel, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I have a Laravel application on Azure Web App behind Azure Front Door and a custom domain.

When using PHP7.4 with Apache all was working correctly.
We now upgraded to PHP8.2, but now NGINX is used as webserver and when doing a redirect after login for example, i'm now being redirected to the azurewebsites.net url instead of the custom domain.

I've followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux#change-site-root

Site is working initially on the custom domain, but when using Laravel's redirect helper, i'm being redirected to the default domain (e.g. .azurewebsites.net) of the app service instance.

Any idea why this is happening and what the solution is?

I tried to add a redirect in the nginx config as well as a middleware in Laravel to redirect back to the custom domain when the url is .azurewebsites.net, but both ended up in TOO MANY REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when using the API on the azure side you should specify **Redirect URL** or **callback URL** on the client side, and then when calling a request on the server you should specify it as well.

Here's a  [good example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/tutorial-php-database-app) of working in Azure domains

Comment: I appreciate your input, but am failing to see a solution in the provided article.
And i don't really understand what you mean with "the API".

I've setup the custom domain in the Front Door configuration and i have two App Services behind it.

Before, when using Apache, doing a redirect in Laravel (e.g. `Redirect::to('dashboard')`) just worked. Now with NGINX, it redirects to the default app service domain name.

So to me seems some sort of NGINX config. But setting the server_name didn't help in this issue.

Comment: what is the `APP_URL` value of `.env` file?

Comment: The`APP_URL` is set to the custom domain.

Comment: can you share the default nginx config file on /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default ? because every time you restart the server this config file is reset to default, can you sahre the current file without any confidential subjects